# Android: how to detect when items are successfully loaded in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am using `ListView` which gets populated by the use of `Adapter`.
One of its features is also highlighting position on the list for the user with `listView.getChildAt(savedViewPosition).setSelected(true)`.

At the conformation change, I would like to retaing poisiton of the selected item.
However, while I have tried several options, the best so far was to set a delay with `.postDelay()` and wait for the `listView` to load.

With this in mind, I would ask if there is any call that would enable me to wait until the items are loaded/visible and then posting the method immediately?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that could be accomplished by overriding notifyDataSetChanged() and selecting the item once the data has been loaded. There may be more to it to fit the exact behavior you want but it should be workable.

See the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()).

Comment: First of all, thank you for the comment. However, I need this with the configuration change and not when the data are updated so the solution is not that sensible.